# why does IIS ignore web.config when it comes to <authentication mode="Windows"/>?

Tags: iis, authentication

I'm using IIS and trying to deploy a web application that needs authentication mode="Windows".

However on every machine I try this on, simply deploying the web app doesn't work.  The web.config says

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
```

but under the IIS manager it says

```
Windows Authentication Disabled
```

So I save a backup of my web.config, then I use IIS to enable windows authentication.  After I do that, my application works fine ***but the web.config file is unchanged***.

I have to automatically create a new instance of this web app for each client.  Requiring an IT guy to manually go to each webapp and turn on this feature is a non-starter.  I need the web.config file to work, or I need to know what config file I have to change to make it work.  I've spent days trying to get this sorted without success.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific? IIS6, IIS7 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm presuming that you are authenticating users against some windows user accounts? I am also presuming that you want the browser to pop up the username and password challenge?

There are two different things at work here.

The `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` setting in `web.config` is just telling ASP.NET to construct an identity based on credentials supplied by IIS rather than by Forms Authentication (or another provider). It is not a setting controlled by IIS and IIS has no visibility of this setting. Also changing this setting in `web.config` will not change the authentication settings for IIS.

When you change the Windows Authentication settings in IIS MMC you are altering a setting in the IIS6 metabase or if you're using IIS7 the `system.webServer/security/authentication` section (in your `web.config` or possibly in `applicationHost.config` depending on how the setting was altered).

So unless you (you know this):

- remove anonymous authentication from the site in IIS MMC, or remove NTFS permissions for the anonymous account on the sites files and folders
- specify Windows Authentication in IIS MMC

You won't get the username and password challenge in the browser regardless of the setting in `system.web/authentication`.

Comment: That was incredibly helpful.  Just the keyword "applicationHost.config" was most of what I needed. 

Some other comments for posterity:
From this link I was able to find the information about how to configure things that I thought should have been in web.config:
   http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference
However at first it looked like I didn't have any of those config files because I use TotalCommander. Apparently you need to have admin privileges to view the directory AND you can only see the files if you're looking at them with a 64bit program (if on a 64 bit box)

Thanks!

Comment: I find it strange that you can enable Windows auth and require specific Windows groups (ASP.Net authorization rules) in the IIS Manager GUI, but there seems to be *no* setting in the GUI to set the web.config authentication mode? Someone correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: @Mister_Tom Do you mean in `system.web` or `system.webServer`? If you mean `system.web` then yes, correct, seems like an oversight, but even then not all IIS specific configs settings have a IIS MMC config app and some don't surface all config options. That said you can configure these *hidden* features/options using the generic Configuration Editor which is available in the IIS Administration Pack: http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/administration-pack

Comment: @Kev yes I mean system.web - strangely the ASP.Net GUI configuration tool in IIS 6 allowed changing of the Authentication mode, but starting in IIS 7 it appears to have gone missing from the GUI tools. I'll definitely check out the Configuration Editor - thanks for the tip.